# OpenGL: Draw color with mask on a background image

Tags: opengl

I need to draw a color with some shape onto an image. My thought was to supply a mask with the given shape (say, hearts), then fill the rectangular area with the color and use the mask to render it over the final image.

[image: Color] 
Masked by:

[image: Mask]
 PLUS

[image: Base]
 EQUALS:

[image: Final]

The rectangle color is decided at runtime - that's why I don't draw the colored heart on my own.

The black heart image is transparent (alpha is 0) anywhere except for the heart (alpha is 255).
I tried using:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO)
```

where the source is the solid color, and the destination is the alpha channel image.
I used https://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php for help.

However the bottom image (tree) is being used as the DST image...
Seems like I need an intermediate buffer to first render the blue heart, then do a second render onto the tree.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: If you know the color of the final heart (say, blue) then pass it as an *uniform* (you use OGL >1.1, right?) to the shader and use it as the color for fragments. And draw the heart after drawing the tree, either disabling depth test or moving the heart a bit towards the camera.

Comment: I don't know the color - it will be a different color every time, decided at runtime...

Comment: But you do know it right before drawing the heart, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tree is drawn before, it will appear in the dest Color and change your final result.

You are right, you need an intermediate buffer to store which part of the quand should be rendered, with the shape of your heart.

OpenGL provide a perfect tool for this, it's called stencil buffer.

In your case i will render my scene like usual (the tree)

Then i will enable the stencil buffer `glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);`

Disable the write to the colorBuffer `glColorMask(false, false, false, false);`,

Draw only the heart with the appropriate mask. `glStencilMask(0xFF);`

Then you draw your colored quad with stencil test enable with `glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF)`

Don't forget to clear your stencil buffer each frame `glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);`

You can find some good tutorials online: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple way to do this in legacy OpenGL (which I assume you're using) that does not require a stencil buffer:

```java
public void render() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    // Regular blending
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    // Discard transparent pixels. Not strictly necessary but good for performance in this case.
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.01f);

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, treeTexture);
    drawQuad();

    glColor3f(1,0,1); // Your color goes here
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, maskTexture);
    drawQuad();
}

private void drawQuad() {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex2f(0,1);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f(1,1);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex2f(1,0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Here, `treeTexture` is the tree texture, and `maskTexture` is the *white-on-transparent* heart shape.

Result:

[image]

The principle is that in the legacy OpenGL pipeline, you can use `glColor*` before `glVertex*` to specify a color that the texture color (in this case white or transparent) is multiplied by component-wise.

Note that with this method you can easily render multiple colored shapes in multiple different colors without needing any (relatively expensive) clears of the stencil buffer. I suggest cropping the mask texture to the boundaries of the actual mask shape, to save the GPU the small effort of discarding all the transparent fragments.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that when moving up to modern OpenGL, this method cannot be used?

Comment: With modern OpenGL you'd do the exact same thing, but from inside a fragment shader instead of using the fixed-function pipeline, which makes the code look completely different. In essence, you'd pass your desired color as a uniform variable to the fragment shader, and multiply it with the color you get from the mask texture sampler to produce the final fragment color. If you're using modern OpenGL, you can paste your fragment shader into your question and I'll show you how to modify it.

Comment: In either case, this is the proper way to do it. No additional buffer is necessary.